# Deleting a pointer which is used by multiple variables

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, destructor

I have a question about properly deleting/deallocating memory in C++.

Suppose I have the following...(Assume A,  B, C, D are classes. B and C have instance variable `A* a`. D has two instance variables, `B* b` and `C* c`)

```
A* a = new A();
B* b = new B(a);
C* c = new C(a);
D* d = new D(b, c);
```

B and C's destructor:

```
B::~B() { delete a; }
C::~C() { delete a; }
```

D's destructor:

```
D::~D() { delete b; delete c; }
```

Now when I call

```
delete d;
```

I get an "access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee" (I'm in Visual Studio 2010). I think this is because

-`D`'s destructor is trying to 'delete' the same memory (`a`) twice when `a` has already been deallocated.

-I have two pointers (one in `B` and another in `C`) both pointing to the same address (of `a`), and when D's destructor deletes `b` (which in turn calls `delete a`), this memory is now set as freed.

-Now when `D`'s destructor deletes `c`, `c` tries to call `delete a` on its own which fails because `a` has already been deallocated.

I am relatively new to C++ but not new to programming. I looked this up and saw that smart pointers (like shared_ptr) can solve this, but what is the best practice in this case? Should I just have created two separate `A` objects?

Comment: Use [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: Don't use pointers at all. Most likely you don't need them, and even if you did, they are a very advanced topic that's extremely hard to understand and use right, so don't do that just yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your design plans to **share** the same `a` with both `b` and `c`, you should encapsulate the pointer in a **shared** pointer.

However, making use of pointers at all is only required in some cases. In most cases, references also do the job. In your case, if the context in which you define these four instances should also restrict their lifetimes, simply define them as values:

```
A a;
B b(a);
C c(a);
D d(b, c);
```

To pass the objects *by reference*, use reference types in both the constructor and private members. And do not call `delete` in their destructor.

```
class B {
    A & m_a;
public:
    B (A &a) : m_a(a) {
    }
};
```

A very important difference about references and pointers (there are more than you might think in the beginning) is that you can't change references (only the referenced value). Also (which is an implication of this fact), it has to be assigned when the variable is defined. That's why you have to use the strange initialization syntax (`:m_a(a)`) in the constructor instead of an assignment in its body (`m_a = a` won't work).

Also, **never** delete an instance in the destructor which was passed in the constructor, **unless** you know what you're doing, which implies that you know the Rule of Three. But smart pointers made this [obsolete](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Comment: I would disagree that the initialization list syntax is "strange", but otherwise +1.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes. Just to have it mentioned, this also counts for the original code (`delete a` is bad).

Comment: @ZacHowland It *is* strange for *beginners* which come from different but syntactically similar languages (in particular Java). Beginners often wonder why to not simply use assignment statements in the constructor and I totally agree if they argue that it looks nicer.

Comment: @leemes Fair point, though "strange" is still not the word I would use.  "Different" or "C++ specific" ... but it is actually quite an elegant way to initialize data members (in comparison to the *inferior* managed languages).

Comment: @leemes Well it sort of counts in reverse for the original code, whose `A` was never at risk of _spontaneous_ destruction, pre the `delete` shenanigans.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is in deciding who owns the `A` object. It appears that both `B` and `C` consider themselves owners, because they `delete` the pointer to `a`. However, they did not allocate `A`, so generally they should not be deleting it either.

There are several solutions to this problem:

1. **Use objects instead of pointers** - This simplifies memory management a lot, because the compiler does the right thing for you.
2. **Make a new `A` object inside `B`'s and `C`'s constructors** - you can now `delete a`, because you *own* it. When you do this, you must also implement a copy constructor and an assignment operator.
3. **Do the implicit transfer of ownership** - This is the trickiest one for the callers to get right: once the caller passes `A` to a constructor of `B` or `C`, the caller must stop using the object pointer at once. `B` and `C` assume ownership of their `A`, deleting it in the destructor.
4. **Pass owned objects** - If you control the lifetime of `B` and `C`, you can make sure that `A` exists during these objects' lifetime. In this case `B` and `C` may reference `A`, and but not touch the pointer in the destructor.

As you can see, the language offers you a lot of flexibility in controlling the ownership. In general, you should start with the simplest models, and progress to more complex ones when the simpler ones no longer fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

When using pointers you need to make sure that the pointers are suitably owned: the easiest approach is to create individual owners, e.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A());
std::unique_ptr<B> b(new B(a.get()));
std::unique_ptr<C> c(new C(a.get()));
std::unique_ptr<D> d(new D(b.get(), c.get());
```

None of the destructors would do anything as the `std::unique_ptr<T>`s would own the objects and release them. That is, the pointers are used as links but not as resource handles.

Of course, you might even get away without allocating any memory on the heap at all:

```
A a;
B b(&a);
C c(&c);
D d(&b, &c);
```

If you want to make sure that an allocate object stays around as long as there is any user, using `std::shared_ptr<T>` is the appropriate approach: the pointers are used as shared resource handles and using reference counting is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is a question of **ownership**. Currently both class B and C assume they own the A object that was passed to them at construction (we know this because the destroy the object in their destructor). If these objects should/continue to **own** an A object, then you must create a second A. However, if it is okay for them to share the object neither B nor C should be responsible for deleting the object (since it is shared). One way to solve this problem is to change B and C to only **know** an A object. This means the A object will need to be deleted by someone else. One way to do this is with a shared_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, you can get away without needing to allocate memory on the heap (that is, you don't need to call `new`).  If you are coming from a managed language (Java, C#, etc), it is a difficult habit to break.  Depending on your design goals, your code could be written as

```
A a;
B b(a);
C c(a);
D d(b, c);
```

If your design does require pointers and dynamic memory usage, you should use smart pointer wrappers (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`).  In this particular case, I would recommend going with `std::shared_ptr` as you are using (e.g. sharing) the pointers in multiple places:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> pA = std::make_shared<A>();
std::shared_ptr<B> pB = std::make_shared<B>(a);
std::shared_ptr<C> pC = std::make_shared<C>(a);
std::shared_ptr<D> pD = std::make_shared<D>(b, c);
```